# Can't resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to inject service in my component and I get this error:

[image]

`news.component.ts`

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from './index';


declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'news-selector-comp',
    templateUrl:'news.html'

})

export class NewsSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

      isLoading = true;
      isError   = false;
      News:any;


      constructor(public newsService:NewsService) { }

}
```

`news.module.ts`

[image]

`news.service.ts`

```
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { News, NewsImp } from './news';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class NewsService {

_url = '<%= SYSTEM_URL%>/news';
token   = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
user_id = window.localStorage.getItem('user_id');
    constructor(private _http:Http) {

    }

    getNews() : Observable<NewsImp[]> {

        return  this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').map(res => res.json());
    }

    postNews() : Observable<News[]> {

      var headers = new Headers();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      var news = {
        user_id: this.user_id,
        token  : this.token
      };

        return this._http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify(news), {headers:headers}).map( res => res.json().data);
  }

}
```

Comment: can you show us NewsService code?

Comment: Always post your code as code, not as an image.

Comment: Add HttpModule in imports array of NewsModule

Comment: What's with the random mix of formatting and images? Please give all relevant code (and error messages!) as correctly-formatted code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue myself, but for perhaps a different reason.  I notice you are using the "barrels" approach here:

```
import { NewsService } from './index';
```

Try importing the NewsService class directly from the file it has been exported from.  This seems to be a common issue.

Answer (score 0):

Everything look okay according to your code expect below part.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NewsService} from './index';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule],   
  //In you main module, you should use BrowswerModule as shown here.
  // In feature module you should use CommonModule

  declarations: [NewsSelectorComponent],
  providers:    [NewsService],
  bootstrap:    [NewsSelectorComponent]
})
```

I think this code should work.